# No aparecen los nombres de los campos

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo

Ya hice la vista del modelo que estoy haciendo pero a la hora de verlo en la interfaz de odoo solo me muestra donde se llenan los registros mas no los nombres de los campos

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<odoo>

<record id="mti_Bascula_form" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
        <sheet>
                  <div>
                      <div class="oe_titlle">
                      <field name="Proovedor" widget="many2one_tags"/>
                    <div class="o_row" style="display: flex;">
                        <field name="Operador"/>
                        <field name="Placas_Trac"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o_row" style="display:flex;">
                        <field name="Carta_porte"/>
                        <field name="Destino"/>
                        <field name="Via" required="1"/>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
        </sheet>
    </form>
    </field>
</record>


<record id="mti_bascula" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="res_model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>


<menuitem id="mti_menu_bascula" name="Bascula" parent="stock.menu_stock_root"  sequence="1"/>
<menuitem  action="mti_bascula" parent="mti_menu_bascula" id="bascula_menu" name="Bascula"   sequence="2"/>
````

```

No marca error alguno solo no muestra los nombres de los los campos no se si me olvide de agregar algo

Adjunto imagen de la interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los nombres estan tal cual como los tengo en en modelo en python pero a la hora de ponerlo en el xml no los muestra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar las etiquetas "`group`":

```html
<record id="mti_Bascula_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">Bascula</field>
  <field name="model">mti_bascula</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <sheet>
        <group>
          <field name="Proovedor" widget="many2one_tags" />
        </group>
        <group>
          <group>
            <field name="Operador" />
            <field name="Placas_Trac" />
          </group>
          <group>
            <field name="Carta_porte" />
            <field name="Destino" />
            <field name="Via" required="1" />

          </group>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```